# filtering out list of unordered int from a bigger list

Tags: c#, list, hash

I got an **unordered list** of int. Between 80 to 140 items, value of each item is between 0 and 175.

I'm generating a list of that list, about 5 to 10 millions of them.

I need to process, as fast as possible, all **unique ordered sequence** (excluding duplicate).

The way I'm doing it right now is creating a hash of all value of a list and inserting it into a hashset.

two hot spot while profiling is the ToArray() **HOTSPOT1** and Array.Sort()   **HOTSPOT2**

is there a better way of doing that task or a better alternative to fix the 2 hotspots? speed is important.

small demo, I tried to replicate as much as possible

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Example
    {
        //some other properties

        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var checkedUnlock = new HashSet<int>();
            var data = FakeData();

            foreach (List<Example> subList in data)
            {
                var hash = CalcHash(subList.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray());  // HOTPSOT1

                var newHash = checkedUnlock.Add(hash);

                if (newHash)
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }

        static int CalcHash(int[] value)
        {
            Array.Sort(value); // HOTPSOT2

            int hash;
            unchecked // https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/40868
            {
                hash = (int)2166136261;
                var i = value.Length;
                while (i-- > 0)
                    hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ value[i];
            }

            return hash;
        }

        //don't look at this, this is just to fake data
        static List<List<Example>> FakeData()
        {
            var data = new List<List<Example>>();

            var jMax = 10; //normally between 80 and 140
            var idMax = 25; //normally between 0 and 175
            var rnd = new Random(42);
            var ids = Enumerable.Range(0, idMax).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
            {
                //force duplicate
                if(i % 50000 == 0)
                {
                    ids = Enumerable.Range(0, idMax).ToArray();
                    rnd = new Random(42);
                }

                for (int r = 0; r < idMax; ++r)
                {
                    int randomIndex = rnd.Next(idMax);
                    int temp = ids[randomIndex];
                    ids[randomIndex] = ids[r];
                    ids[r] = temp;
                }

                var subList = new List<Example>();
                data.Add(subList);

                for (int j = 0; j < jMax; ++j)
                {
                    subList.Add(new Example() { Id = ids[j] });                    
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CalcHash` has a (what I would call "unexpected") side effect of reordering its array parameter.

Comment: @spender at this point reordering is not "important" since it's a copy, not the original

Comment: Can your lists contain duplicates? That is, can the value 22, for example, exist twice in a list?

Comment: @JimMischel no each value show once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can save some time by re-using one array of bigger size instead of allocating new array every time causing extra memory traffic and garbage collection.

That would require custom sorting implementation which knows that even though array can have 1000 items, for current run only first 80 items needs to be sorted (and same for hash). It looks quicksort operating on subrange of ids should work fine. Quick sample of idea (haven't tested in details)

```
int[] buffer = new int[1000];
foreach (List<Example> subList in data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < subList.Count; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = subList[i].Id;
    }
    var hash = CalcHashEx(buffer, 0, subList.Count - 1);

    var newHash = checkedUnlock.Add(hash);

    if (newHash)
    {
        //do something
    }
}


public static void QuickSort(int[] elements, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left, j = right;
    int pivot = elements[(left + right) / 2];
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (elements[i] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (elements[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j)
        {
            // Swap
            int tmp = elements[i];
            elements[i] = elements[j];
            elements[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if (left < j)
    {
        QuickSort(elements, left, j);
    }
    if (i < right)
    {
        QuickSort(elements, i, right);
    }
}

static int CalcHashEx(int[] value, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    QuickSort(value, startIndex, endIndex);

    int hash;
    unchecked // https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/40868
    {
        hash = (int)2166136261;
        var i = endIndex + 1;
        while (i-- > 0)
            hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ value[i];
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Comment: hmm this is something that i need to look at, Array.Sort already does a quicksort so i will try to handle the array myself and get back to you, in 1-2 hours

Comment: pre-allocating the array and doing the loop manually (instead of .Select()) seem to save 10-13% at runtime, going to wait a few hours and i think you will get the green check :-)

Comment: The new `Span<T>` type might make this even easier to do.

Comment: @Fredou BTW, if lists processing order doesn't matter, you can parallel foreach loop going through sublitst to keep all CPU cores busy. However, need to take into account thread safety accessing shared hashset.

Comment: @dlxeon that big list of 5-10 millions items is already being used by a parallel foreach, it was the inner list that was slowing thing down which now is fixed by doing a mix of your solution and Joel, managing myself the array and doing it while the inner list is being built

Answer (score 3):

So you have an array that can contain up to 140 items, and all values are in the range 0 through 175. All values in the array are unique, and order doesn't matter. That is, the array `[20, 90, 16]` will be considered the same as `[16, 20, 90]`.

Given that, you can represent a single array as a set of 175 bits. Better, you can create the set without having to sort the input array.

You represent a set in C# as a [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx). To compute the hash code of your array, you create the set, and then you iterate over the set to get the hash code. It looks something like this:

```
private BitArray HashCalcSet = new BitArray(175);
int CalcHash(int[] a, int startIndex)
{
    // construct the set
    HashCalcSet.SetAll(false);

    for (var i = startIndex; i < a.Length; ++i)
    {
        HashCalcSet[a[i]] = true;
    }

    // compute the hash
    hash = (int)2166136261;
    for (var i = 174; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (HashCalcSet[i])
        {
            hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ value[i];
        }
    }
    return hash;
}
```

That eliminates the sorting as well as the `ToArray`. You have to loop over the `BitArray` a couple of times, but three passes over the `BitArray` is quite possibly faster than sorting.

One problem I see with your solution is in how you're using the `HashSet`. You have this code:

```
var hash = CalcHash(subList.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray());  // HOTPSOT1

var newHash = checkedUnlock.Add(hash);

if (newHash)
{
    //do something
}
```

That code mistakenly assumes that if the hash codes for two arrays are equal, then the arrays are equal. You're generating a 32-bit hash code for a 175-bit quantity. There will definitely be hash collisions. You're going to end up saying that two of your arrays are identical, when they aren't.

If that is a concern to you, let me know and I can edit my answer to provide a solution.

### Allowing for comparison

If you want the ability to compare items for equality, rather than just checking if their hash codes are the same, you need to create an object that has `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. You'll insert that object into your `HashSet`. The simplest of those objects would contain the `BitArray` I described above, and methods that operate on it. Something like:

```
class ArrayObject
{
    private BitArray theBits;
    private int hashCode;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (object == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        ArrayObject other = (ArrayObject)obj;
        // compare two BitArray objects
        for (var i = 0; i < theBits.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (theBits[i] != other.theBits[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return hashCode;
    }

    public ArrayObject(int hash, BitArray bits)
    {
        theBits = bits;
        hashCode = hash;
    }
}
```

The idea being that you construct the `BitArray` and the hash code in the method as described above (although you'll have to allocate a new `BitArray` for each call), and then create and return one of these `ArrayObject` instances.

Your `HashSet` becomes `HashSet<ArrayObject>`.

The above works, but it's a big of a memory hog. You could reduce the memory requirement by creating a class that contains just three `long` integers. Instead of using a `BitArray`, you manipulate the bits directly. You map the bits so that numbers 0 through 63 modify bits 0 through 63 in the first number. Numbers 64 through 127 correspond to bits 0 through 63 of the second number, etc. You don't have to save a separate hash code then, because it'd be easy to compute from the three longs, and equality comparison becomes a lot easier, too.

The class looks something like this. Understand, I haven't tested the code, but the idea should be sound.

```
class ArrayObject2
{
    private long l1;
    private long l2;
    private long l3;

    public ArrayObject2(int[] theArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < theArray.Length; ++i)
        {
            var rem = theArray[i] % 63;
            int bitVal = 1 << rem;
            if (rem < 64) l1 |= bitVal;
            else if (rem < 128) l2 |= bitVal;
            else l3 |= bitVal;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as ArrayObject2;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return l1 == other.l1 && l2 == other.l2 && l3 == other.l3;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // very simple, and not very good hash function.
        return (int)l1;
    }
}
```

As I commented in the code, the hash function there isn't great. It will work, but you can do better with a little research.

This approach has the advantage of using less memory than the `BitArray` or the `Boolean` array. It'll probably be slower than the array of `bool`. It *might* be faster than the `BitArray` code. But whatever the case, it'll keep you from making the mistaken assumption that identical hash codes equals identical arrays.

Comment: This is the answer, though the BitArray will most likely be slower than a plain bool array.

Comment: @MineR Quite possibly, although if he needs to take the next step and create an object so that he can do a real comparison in the face of hash collisions, the `BitArray` is going to occupy significantly less space. And if space becomes a concern, I can do better than a `BitArray`.

Comment: @JimMischel That is a great solution and should be faster, than my answer. I thought about that, but assumed values in lists may not be unique.

Comment: interesting way, i'm going to check the difference between what i implemented based on dlxeon and joel answer/comments and this, in the mean time the hash collision so far didn't create issue but i would be very interested in knowing how to fix that and seeing the processing time cost too

Comment: @Fredou As I understand, solution is to have an object of custom class that internally like BitArray and represents your array. That object will have .GetHashCode() method implemented and .CompareTo(), then you can use Dictionary/Hashset of your objects directly and .net framework will use .GetHashCode, but if hashes are equal, full .CompareTo methods will be invoked for identical hashes to ensure that is in fact same or different objects. BitArray is memory-efficient, but lacks standard efficient comparison method. You can do class similar to BitArray by yourself for best resutls.

Comment: could you clarify what is value[i] in the code block ? i'm not really sure also it is missing the unchecked {}, also what if i take the index for the hash?

Comment: look at my answer, I removed two loop from your idea and i'm using an array of bool instead of bitarray

Comment: @Fredou The description that dlxeon gave covers the basics. I should have time in a few hours to provide a code example.

Answer (score 1):

This version of `CalcHash()` will let you remove the `.ToArray()` and replaces the `Array.Sort()` with something different that can act on a sequence, rather than needing the entire set... so that's both hot spots.

```
static int CalcHash(IEnumerable<int> value)
{
    value = value.OrderByDescending(i => i);

    int hash;
    unchecked // https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/40868
    {
        hash = (int)2166136261;
        foreach(var item in value)
        {
            hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ item;
        }
    }

    return hash;
}
```

I'm not sure how `OrderByDescending()` will fare in comparison. I suspect it will be slower than `Array.Sort()`, but still be an over-all win because of eliminating `ToArray()`... but you'll need to run the profiler again to know for sure.

There may also be improvement you can get from eliminating or reducing branching, via `.GroupBy()`, and running the code on the `.First()` item in each group:

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(sub => CalcHash(sub.Select(x => x.Id)));
foreach(List<Example> subList in groups.Select(g => g.First()))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: the linq OrderBy/ OrderByDescending is 2x slower than ToArray() / Array.Sort based on what i'm seeing in my code (40% in the profiler vs 10.2% + 8.5%)

Comment: I knew `OrderBy()` needed a generally slower algorithm than `Array.Sort()`, because it can't know the sequence is bounded in a meaningful way. I was hoping saving the array creation would net a win. What about instead changing `ToArray()` to `ToList()`, and changing `CalcHash()` to just need an `IList<int>`? That's basically the same algorithm, but `ToList()` is often a little faster than `ToArray()`.

Comment: if i understand correctly, under the hood a list.sort is actually using array.sort so going with a list add one layer that is not really needed. i need to check again to confirm

Comment: yup. Array.Sort is used; https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,af8f80d5b9f26264

Comment: But it's not the Sort() hot spot I was hoping to improve by suggesting a list. It's the ToArray() hot spot. Knowing that List.Sort() uses Array.Sort(), and that the List already maintains an internal array for this, I intuit the List.Sort() should not be meaningfully slower. But there is a potential that a ToList() call can be somewhat faster than a ToArray() call (and it could also be worse, but I believe faster is the more usual, and that's why we measure.)

Comment: just did the profiling (ran twice) with ToList() / List.Sort(); 7.5% and 10.3%, weird result for the sort, way slower than Array.Sort()

Comment: But still maybe a win... 17.8 < 18.7. Not much, but something. Of course, the _**best**_ option is to compute the hash as you build the array, and return _both_ with the sample data. The new support around the `ValueTuple` type can help with that (`List<(int, List<Example>)>`)

Comment: i think this is what i will do, in a few hours, since I control the whole flow

Comment: fyi, i used your idea (last comment) and dlxeon idea which work nicely

Answer (score 0):

going to put this here since it make no sense to put it in a comment

so far what I have done is created an array of boolean and setting the index of the item to true when present and I replaced the CalcHash with;

```
        unchecked
        {
            hash = (int)2166136261;
            var i = theMaxLength;
            while (i-- > 0)
                if(testing[i]) //the array of boolean
                {
                    hash = (hash  * 16777619) ^ i;
                    testing[i] = false;
                }
        }
```

doing so I removed the ToArray() and the Array.Sort() completely, this solution is kind of built from the dlxeon/jim/joel answer

i dropped the runtime by about 20-25% which is great

Comment: I got another idea: if your input sequence doesn't have duplicates and you really don't want to handle hash collisions (but I would recommend handle hash collisions), and you can modify hash algorithm (to return different result, than current implementation for same data), then you don't actually need the boolean array itself. You can just calculate hash on the fly as you are processing your input list of ids when you decide to set some values of boolean array to 'true'. And then you can do that in a loop taking original objects (no need to create buffer array of int for that)

Comment: Where did your array of `Boolean` come from? Out of context, the code here doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @JimMischel in my code block in my original question, other proprieties of the class example got one to the parent of example which contains a few more properties (when i wrote the question i didn't think about mentioning it, my mistake) since that parent also handle the creation of the example class, the array of boolean come from it